# Why does radio button needs to be clicked twice to be selected?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
     <h4 style="width:100%">{{question.question}}</h4>
     <ion-list  ng-repeat="choice in choices"
                ng-show="{{question.id}}=={{choice.question_id}}">
         <ion-radio style="width:100%; float:left;" 
                name="{{question.id}}" 
                ng-value="{{choice.point}}"
                ng-Model="test[question.id-1]">
            {{choice.choice}}
         </ion-radio>
     </ion-list>
</div>
```

it is supposed to be clicked only once to be selected but it needs two clicks to be selected.

Comment: you want that to be clicked twice or is it happening twice?

Comment: Please edit your title to ask a question. This will clear up the ambiguity you have now. Don't stick tags on it.

Comment: it is supposed to be clicked only once to be selected but it needs two clicks to be selected.